# How to use a <img> tag to send javascript to a page

Tags: javascript, html, code-injection

I have a tracking pixel img like this one:

```
<img ... width=1 height=1 src="http://trk.dom123.com/file.aspx?type=1&cp=1" />
```

I would like to be able to return a javascript from this src.
This will then use me to make the analysis I am required to do.

Meaning calling the IMG src will result with a script I generate in my server, injected to the page that fired the pixel (the IMG tga).

Is it possible? if not please suggest any other alternatives.

Many thanks.

Comment: I really hope this is not possible :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, an `img` tag will not process javascript.  It will result in a broken image.  The obvious answer is to simply do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://trk.dom123.com/file.aspx?type=1&cp=1"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible with modern browsers due to XSS attacks. You will have to include any javascript with a `<script>` tag

See http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, alternative would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://trk.dom123.com/file.aspx?type=1&cp=1"></script>
```